# React - Antd - Show/Hide Columns in table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to resolve one problem.
How can I show/hide columns in table using Ant Design in React?

```
export const columns = () => [
 {
   key: "anyKeyOne",
   title: "Title one",
   dataSource: "AnyOne",
   hide: true
 },
 {
   key: "anyKeyTwo",
   title: "TitleTwo",
   dataSource: "AnyTwo",
   hide: false
 }
]

hideColumns = () => {
 // 
}

render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Table 
     dataSource={store.data}
     columns={this.hideColumns}
   />
  </div>
 )
}
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a boolean state property like hideColumn

```
<div>
   <Table 
     dataSource={store.data}
     columns={this.state.hideColumn? this.state.columns: this.state.columns}
   />
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain the thought?

Comment: I assume your columns and hideColumns are two different setting for columns.So by setting this.state.hideColumn to true or false, you can show or hide columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to build your visible column array. It uses dataIndex to compare the column name needed to be shown.

Form the arrayOfColumnNeeded by pushing values from a checkbox group maybe.

```
let  columnsDisplayed = _.remove(columns, function(n) {
  return arrayOfColumnsNeeded.includes(n.dataIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a className field in the object and add a css property 'display: none' to that class

```
 {
   key: "anyKeyOne",
   title: "Title one",
   dataSource: "AnyOne",
   className: "hide"
 }
```